# Invalid Namespace Error while executing batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, wmic

I have been using a batch file for the past 1 year however suddenly I started getting below error while running it:

> ERROR:Description = Invalid namespace

For below block of code:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims= " %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') do (
        IF NOT "%%~f"=="" (
            set /a FormattedDate=10000 * %%f + 100 * %%d + %%a
            set FileDate=!FormattedDate:~-2,2!!FormattedDate:~-4,2!!FormattedDate:~-10,4!
            set Month=!FormattedDate:~-4,2!
        )
    )
```

I am not that familiar with bat files & was just using the above code to get current date in required format.

System: Windows 10

Please assist. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

On a more general note I am actually trying to get 3 things from system date:

- File Date:23032018
- Month:03
- Date:23Mar2018

Comment: It would help were you to tell us what you're expecting as the set values for `%FileDate%` and `%Month%`. You could also show us what is returned from just running the following at the command prompt: `WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year`. Please make sure that you use the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49445437/edit) to add that information to your question, _don't add it to the comment section_.

Comment: @Compo I added the requirement.

Comment: Your posted script does not `Set` a `%Date%` variable, and you haven't told us what is returned by the `WMIC` command I asked you to run and add to your question.

Comment: @Compo The thing is, the error is cming while the WMIC command is running so I can't provide the output. Anyway if it helps, the command returns the system date in a particular format which I substr here: `set FileDate=!FormattedDate:~-2,2!!FormattedDate:~-4,2!!FormattedDate:~-10,4!`

Comment: What happens then if you select the NameSpace you need, i.e.`/NameSpace:\\root\cimv2`, _(the Default)_?

Comment: @Compo I have no idea how to do that!! Can you provide some more insight? I am really new to this.

Comment: Did you open a new `cmd.exe` window and enter the command I gave you in the first comment, or did you run it from a batch file? I need it running directly at the Command prompt. If you get the same error then try it like this instead: `WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\cimv2 Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year`. If that doesn't change things, just enter `WMIC Context` and tell me what it reads for `NAMESPACE             :`

Comment: @Compo So `WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\cimv2 Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year` is giving the same Namespace error. For `WMIC Context` I am getting `NAMESPACE             : root\cimv2` as namespace.

Comment: Well we've determined that the issue has nothing whatsoever to do with your batch file, is this the first time you've used WMIC? and is this the first time you've received an error when using it? What happens if you try a different command: `WMIC OS LIST STATUS`?

Comment: @Compo I have used this script for like a year now [Same system, same windows 10]. Only since last week it started giving me these issues !! The same error is being thrown for different command as well.

Comment: I would suggest try to determine whether your PC or maybe your `Windows\System32\wbem` directory is corrupted. In the meantime, there are other ways to get the information you need, without using WMIC, what else have you tried? _BTW, you can't have been using that script for a year because it is nowhere close to determining the information your need._

Comment: @Compo I am using that particular block of code in a script since a year :).. I have few more substr & if statements after that to get the data in the way I require. I think i can manipulate %date% to get my required date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to get the variables you require:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "df=%TEMP%\~foo.ddf"&Set "tf=%TEMP%\~%Random%"
Set /A "Jan=1,Feb=2,Mar=3,Apr=4,May=5,Jun=6,Jul=7,Aug=8,Sep=9,Oct=10,Nov=11,Dec=12"
(   Echo .Set InfHeader=""&Echo .Set InfSectionOrder=""&Echo .Set InfFooter="%%2"
    For /L %%A In (1 1 4) Do Echo .Set InfFooter%%A=""
    Echo .Set Cabinet="OFF"&Echo .Set Compress="OFF"&Echo .Set DoNotCopyFiles="ON"
    Echo .Set RptFileName="NUL")>"%df%"
MakeCab /D InfFileName="%tf%" /F "%df%">Nul
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2,3,5" %%A In ("%tf%") Do (Set mmm=%%A
    Set /A "mm=%%A,dd=1%%B-100,yyyy=%%C")
Del "%tf%" "%df%">Nul 2>&1
Set "mm=10%mm%"&Set "DStr=%dd%%mmm%%yyyy%"
Set "FileDate=%dd%%mm:~-2%%yyyy%"&Set "Month=%mm:~-2%"
For %%A In (FileDate Month DStr) Do Call Echo %%%%%%A%%%% = %%%%A%%
Pause
```

The last two lines have been added just to show you the variables which were set; *do not change any of the content before that point*:

Comment: It works!! And I didn't understand a line of it!!! Can I get some quick explanation as to where the date is actually coming from and how!!